# How to select multiple objects from one field in SQL

Tags: sql

So Here is the problem I have a requirement where I need a customer type to equal two different things.

To Cover the requirement I don't need the customer type to equal Client, or Non client but equal Client, and Non_Client.

Here is an example of what I have worked on so far. If you know a better way of optimizing this as well as solving the problem please let me know.

The out put should look like this

```
 CustomerID  CustomerType  CustomerType 
 --------------------------------------
 2345        Client        NonClient


Select TB1.Customer_ID, IB1.Customer_Type, AS Non_client IB1.Customer_Type AS Client
From Client TB1, Client_ReF XB1, Client_Instr IB1, Client_XREC FB1
Where XB1.Client_NO = TB1.Client_NO
AND FB1.Client_ACCT = TB1.ACCT
AND XB1.Client_Instruct_NO = IB1.Client_Instruct_NO
AND FB1.Customer_ID= TB1. Client_NO
Where IB1.Client = 'Client' 
AND IB1.Non_Client = 'NonClient'
```

I have omitted a few other filters that I felt were unnecessary. This also may not make sense, but I tried to change up the names of stuff as to keep myself in compliance.

Comment: Can you try to post table structure and some data for output? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: **Edit** your question and show us the `create table` statements and the queries you have tried, some sample data and the output based on that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregations you can do it like this:

```
select type from TableName
group by type
having sum(case when client = 'Client' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1 and
       sum(case when client = 'NonClient' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Select TB1.Customer_ID, IB1.Customer_Type AS Non_client IB2.Customer_Type AS Client
From Client TB1
Inner join Client_ReF XB1 ON(TB1.Client_NO = XB1.Client_NO)
Inner join Client_XREC FB1 ON(FB1.Customer_ID= TB1. Client_NO AND FB1.Client_ACCT = TB1.ACCT)
Inner join Client_Instr IB1 ON(XB1.Client_Instruct_NO = IB1.Client_Instruct_NO)
Inner join Client_Instr IB2 ON(XB1.Client_Instruct_NO = IB2.Client_Instruct_NO), 
Where IB1.Client = 'Client' 
AND IB2.Non_Client = 'NonClient'
```

**Notes:**

1. `Client_Instr` table is used twice with different aliases.
2. I've changed your implicit joins to explicit ones. Implicit joins are out of date for more then 20 years now.
3. The statement is based on the one you posted. Since no sample data was provided I could not verify that it's actually working properly.

Answer (score -1):

If this is in sql you would do something like:

```
SELECT * from clients c
WHERE c.client = 'Client' AND c.client = 'NonClient'
```

I added the table clients just for the example but you need to replace this table/columns with the values that apply to your example.

Comment: This won't return any records, as there can't possibly be any record where the field client is 'Client' and 'NonClient' at the same time.

Comment: The logic he is trying to apply doesn't make sense itself. But in this case he wants to retrieve a row that may have both situations applied to it, and the purpose of my answer was to show how to use the AND in sql.

Comment: However you look at it, the OP can only talk of *different* rows, one for 'Client', one for 'NonClient', as *one* field in *one* record can only contain *one* value of course. But I agree, the request is incomprehensible as it is.